# Android Boot-Up BroadCast Not invoking

Tags: android, broadcast, boot

I am currently trying to make a broadcast receiver which will invoke after android device boots and then will run a background service. I have tried many examples but don't know where I'm going wrong. I am following this example:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot
I have imported this whole project in my workspace and tried to run. But the receiver didn't invoked or so.
Please help me out.
**My Testing Device is: Motorolla Xoom with ICS 4.0.3**

**EDIT**

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:name="awais.soft.MyService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="awais.soft.MyService" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="awais.soft.ServicesDemoActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
package awais.soft;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ServicesDemoActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

static final int idBut = Menu.FIRST + 1, idIntentID = Menu.FIRST + 2;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("Awais", "onReceive:");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("awais.kpsoft.MyService");
        context.startService(i);

    }

}
```

}

**Service**

```
package awais.soft;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.is);
    player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();
}
```

}

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"> is not written in manifest

Comment: it was type error..corrected later.

Comment: Kindly Post Your Edited Coding so i can get

Comment: issue resolved dear...It was problem with Device not code..:S
thanks for your kind help and time

Comment: Hey dude any time and welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was fine..:S
The problem was with device..(i.e. Motorolla Zoom ICS 4.0.3)

Now tested on Galaxy Tab With 2.2 and Working fine..

Thanks all for your time

Comment: You need to have the user manually  start your app, then broadcast receivers registered in the manifest should work after that. Unless your app is force closed before reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I am something like this in My app and Its Working for me.

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        //  CustomLog.i("Boot Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifset

```
<receiver android:name=".model.service.DeviceBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"></category>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>        
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```

Please check if you have given permission for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Everything was fine..:S
The problem was with device..(i.e. Motorolla Zoom ICS 4.0.3)

Now tested on Galaxy Tab With 2.2 and Working fine..

Thanks all for your time

Answer (score 1):

see i am posting you eample that will help you

For some applications, you will need to have your service up and running when the device is started, without user intervention. Such applications mainly include monitors (telephony, bluetooth, messages, other events).
At least this feature is currently allowed by the exaggeratedly restrictive Android permissions policy.

**Step 1:** First you'll need to create a simple service, defined in Monitor.java:

```
public class Monitor extends Service {

private static final    String              LOG_TAG = "::Monitor";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service created.");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service started.");
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service destroyed.");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service bind.");
    return null;
}
```

}

**Step 2:** Next we need to create a Broadcast receiver class, StartAtBootServiceReceiver.java:

```
  public class StartAtBootServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
  private static final  String  LOG_TAG=StartAtBootServiceReceiver";
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onReceive:");
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("test.package.Monitor");
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

}

**Step 3:** Finally, your AndroidManifest.xml file must contain the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.package.Monitor"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <service android:name="test.package.Monitor">**
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="test.package.Monitor">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="test.package.StartAtBootServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**I need to highlight some of the most important aspects, key factors for possible errors in implementation:

1) The permission android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED must be provided (in the manifest xml)

2) The installation must be performed in internal storage, not on SDCARD! To enforce this use android:installLocation="internalOnly" in the manifest**

Comment: yes its working properly because i am using this in my Application

Comment: ops..still not invoking..
even other broadcast's are also not working..
like i hav tested on power connected.
I wonder do I hav to introduce activity tag in my manifest??

Comment: Yea already looked.
Perhaps I'm testing it in a wrong way then..:S
Coz application is getting installed perfectly. 
Is it tested in simple way like other applications do???
Install and test??

Comment: Everything was fine..:S
The problem was with device..(i.e. Motorolla Zoom ICS 4.0.3)

Now tested on Galaxy Tab With 2.2 and Working fine..

Thanks all for your time

Comment: @Sakiboy Link is now redirecting. Earlier it was working fine. Please check comment date. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted then you will have trouble in Android Boot-Up BroadCast invoking otherwise you have to ensure your app has required root permissions

Answer (score 0):

The problem persists in the case of devices having android version more than 3.0, by the way its not the problem it has been done for security purposes by google i guess..If u have to run the service on boot you have to make a custom intent & broadcast it. For making custom intent you have to make a service file from where u have to broadcast that intent on boot complete & your service file(that u want to run) will receive that intent on its onReceive method & your service will run.One more thing the service file you will create to call your service that you want to run should be kept on system/app folder of file explorer of device, if your file system shows sorry read only file system then from command prompt do just adb remount & then push the file on device,restart your system your service will run..Cheers!!