# Run program immediately after booting in android?

Tags: android

I need to know why my app didn't run immediately after booting in android real phone? My app run but after a few second.

Comment: If you want to run your app right after the phone boots,explains
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup

Comment: dude see this link here answer is posted my me and also tested by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426189/android-boot-up-broadcast-not-invoking/9426306#9426306

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that your app has been installed in phone memory for your receiver to receive boot completion broadcast, As this broadcast occurs before media scanning.
just add an attribute to manifest file's root element 
`installlocation = "internalOnly"`

rest is same as explained above.

Comment: i made all what u say and program actually run but after few second so i need some way to minimize this time or ignore it at all

Comment: what are you starting in your broadcast receiver? service or activity?